# realloc after free problem ("realloc: invalid next size")

Tags: c, memory-leaks, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've got a strange problem with realloc, here's my code (relevant parts only, too big to post the full code here):

```
char * print_bar(struct bar *ptr) {
    char *buf = NULL;
    char *buftmp = NULL;
    size_t size = 60;
    int count = 0;

    if (ptr) {
        while (count == 0 || count+4 >= size) {
            buftmp = (char *) realloc((void *) buf, size * sizeof (char));
            if (buftmp == NULL) {
                if (buf != NULL) free(buf);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            buf = buftmp;

            count = snprintf(buf, size, "%04d-%02d-%02d\t%02d:%02d:00\t%d\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%d",
                    ptr->year,
                    ptr->month,
                    ptr->day,
                    ptr->hour,
                    ptr->minute,
                    ptr->timeframe,
                    ptr->open,
                    ptr->high,
                    ptr->low,
                    ptr->close,
                    ptr->volume
                    );

            size += 4;
        }
    }

    return buf;
}

char * print_historico(short timeframe) {
    struct barlist *tmp = get_barlist(timeframe);
    struct bar *ptr;
    char * result = NULL;
    char * resulttmp = NULL;
    char * buf;
    int len;

    if (tmp) {
        ptr = tmp->first;
        while (ptr) {
            buf = print_bar(ptr);
            len = (result != NULL) ? strlen(result)+strlen(buf)+1 : strlen(buf)+1;
            resulttmp = (char *)realloc((void *)result, len);
            if (resulttmp == NULL)
            {
                if (result != NULL) free(result);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            result = resulttmp;
            strncat(result, buf, strlen(buf));

            free(buf);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

In my main function i've got the following loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 27; i++) {
    historico = print_historico(i);
    if (historico != NULL)
    {
        puts(historico);
        free(historico);
    }
}
```

If i compile and run it fails with "realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001704f60". If i run with the debugger i see it finishes the first iteration of the main loop ok, freeing the 'historico' variable. When it executes "print_historico" with i=2 it fails on the second iteration of the "while(ptr)" loop.

I can't find a reason, any clue? I've also tried to make a small program to isolate the problem, but i wasn't able.

Comment: 1704f60 is 24MB... seems quite large to me... is that what you're expecting?

Comment: What is the first function actually trying to do?  It appears to be repeatedly trying to print a bunch of text into a buffer, expanding the buffer when it finds out it is too small.  This is probably not a good approach--you should probably start with a size that is very likely to fit all the text, and double it if it doesn't.

Comment: @forsvarir: Not only does the code eventually try to allocate 24 MB, I think it gets there by allocating 60 bytes then 64 then 68 all the way up.  I guess it frees the too-small buffers along the way, but this seems pretty weird.

Comment: @John Zwinck: It's actually allocation two groups of buffers, 60,64 etc in the print_bar function and then combining them (60,120,180 etc) in the print_historico function.  I imagine with those going on at the same time, the memory's looking pretty fragmented by the start of the second run.

Comment: A few nitpicks: don't cast the return value of realloc(); sizeof (char) is always 1 so it's quite redundant; free(NULL) is safe so there's no need to check for that.

Comment: yes... :-( I'm not a very good C coder. I'll think about it, but i can't imagine any other way to do it. The "puts" in the main loop is only a test, i would like to have the return value of print_historico in a buffer because i will need to output it to more than one place (stdout, file, etc). I know how to do it with POSIX (dup, select), but i'm somehow restricted to use ISO C for this code, so i'm a bit lost.

Comment: thanks, i didn't knew free(NULL) is safe... By not casting do you mean calling "realloc()" instead of "(char *)realloc()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strncat(result, buf, strlen(buf));
```

This is a problem. (It *might* be the cause of the problem you are reporting having.)

When the first realloc occurs, the result is not initialized. You really need to put a '\0' in the first char position for the strncat to work (reliably).

```
resulttmp = (char *)realloc((void *)result, len);
        if (resulttmp == NULL)
        {
            if (result != NULL) free(result);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
if(result == NULL) *resulttmp = '\0' // YOU NEED THIS!! First time initialization.
```

Comment: Yes, that the cause! I've found it with valgrind:

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I've found it with valgrind just before you posted... I cant figure out why it failed at the _second_ iteration (and at the second call to print_historicos too), where it's supposed to fail when uninitialized, at the first iteration. Moreover after the first iteration strncat seems to copy correctly over "result" when seen with gdb... I'm posting the code i added below, and which solves the problem.

Comment: I didnt see your solution before my last comment... I'm not posting any code, your's is perfect.

Comment: Learning how to find the problem using valgrind is much better!!

Comment: As to why it "worked", keep in mind that realloc/etc never return less memory than you ask for but it can return more (and you never know when that happens). Valgrind works because it is much stricter than the standard allocators (and being stricter means it's slower). Of course, it's hard to determine why exactly it "worked" (but not initializing the buffer is always wrong).

Comment: ok, thanks! i'll keep in mind that alloc functions can return more memory, i did know, but i use C only from time to time, so its difficult to have those things in mind (i need to rediscover all this things every time i start up something in C)... and thanks for discovering valgrind to me too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to isolate possible memory leaks or misuses.

Or keep trying to distill the broken code into an example you can post.

Edit: I think the while condition may be faulty:

```
while (count == 0 || count+4 >= size)
```

Why don't you print out the values each time and run the program and see what it looks like?

Comment: Thanks! i work with C only from time to time... I knew valgrind from references, but i've never used it. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I think the condition is ok... count receives the number of characters that would be written by snprintf. Size holds the actual buffer size, which i need to be at least as big as count characters. So i want the loop to be executed while size <= count, but size is incremented by 4 at the end of the loop, which makes size <= count+4.